# Get Yii CgridView's dataprovider in jquery

Tags: jquery, yii, cgridview

I'm trying to get all data from yii cgridview, I need to get the dataprovider of cgridview in jquery ajax.

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'id'=>'contacts-grid',
    'dataProvider'=>$arrayDataProvider,
    'gridIcon'=>Yii::app()->request->baseUrl.'/images/user.png',
    'afterAjaxUpdate' => "function(id,data){ $('.tooltip').tooltipster({}); }", 
    'headingText'=>utf8_encode(Yii::t('basecontact', 'Contacts')),  
    'columns'=> array_merge($chkarr,$names),//$names,
    'htmlOptions'=>array(),
));
```

Please anyone help us to get all rows or dataprovider of above grid !!!

Comment: Do you want to send AJAX request and get CGridView in response?

Comment: @SiZE Yes, I need to get only cgridview dataprovider values either in controller or in jquery,

Comment: You mean, that you need to get only dataProvider data (instead of GridView widget) with ajax call?

Answer (score 0):

in your ajax controller action you can use something like this:

```
// get dataprovider with ActiveRecord (or some other method)
// and send it to front
$data = json_encode($arrayDataProvider->getData());
$this->layout = false;
$this->renderText($data);
```